# How to transfer ascii modes using Jsch SFTP transfer?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch channelSftp file transfer which is transfering the file in binary mode. Can any one tell me how to set ascii mode?

Comment: I heard that in SFTP 4 there is ascii mode of transfer...

Comment: Interesting. Indeed there's an SSH_FXF_TEXT_MODE option in the later versions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting ASCII mode in Jsch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791369/setting-ascii-mode-in-jsch)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503622/sftp-upload-in-ascii-mode and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127181/ascii-mode-in-sftp-transfers