# ASCII mode in SFTP transfers

Tags: sftp

What does the ASCII mode in SFTP transfer means. Does it going to transfer the file in text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting SFTP specification regarding text (aka ASCII) access to remote files:

> [5.3.  Determining Server Newline Convention](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-13#section-5.3)
>
> In order to correctly process text files in a cross platform
> compatible way, newline sequences must be converted between client
> and server conventions.
>
> The SSH_FXF_TEXT_MODE file open flag (Section 8.1.1) makes it
> possible to request that the server translate a file to a 'canonical'
> wire format.  This format uses CRLF as the line separator.
>
> Servers for systems using other conventions MUST translate to and
> from the canonical form.

Note that the "text mode"  is supported since SFTP version 4 only. Many existing SFTP implementations (including the most widespread one, the OpenSSH) support SFTP version 3 only. So they do not support text/ASCII mode at all.