# "Carriage Return" is missing in sFTP file

Tags: ftp, sftp, mainframe, ssh2-sftp

Upto now we are transferring file from our mainframes to Windows system(Client system) via Normal FTP. My Client is receving the file with "Carriage Return"(CR) and "Line Feed"(LF) at the end of each file..

Now we are changinf the transfer mechanism to sFTP..Below are the steps I am following
1. Copy the PS file to OMVS system of Mainframe.
2. Run the sFTP commands and send the file to Client system.

Now the problem is..My client is along with the data my client is only receving LF ant end of each line..CR is missing..
I have tried options like "ascii dos unix" in the sftp script and "SBSENDEOL CRLF" in JCL..But no luck

Below is the script i am running

```
ascii
lcd /u/myid
put File1.txt FileNew1.txt
chmod 775 FileNew1.txt
put
```

Below is how they expect the file to be

[image: Expectedformat file]

But this is how the file is received when I run the script I have pasted above

[image]

Please let me know if there is option to achieve CR and LF.

Comment: you need to use binary mode if you want to preserve CR/LF

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFTP Upload in "ASCII" Mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503622/sftp-upload-in-ascii-mode)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127181/ascii-mode-in-sftp-transfers

Comment: @Jakuje Binary means with out giving ASCII in the script...right??
I have tried it, on the other side the file is received in an unknown format..

Comment: Thanks for providing the links @Jakuje ..They seems to be setting with respect to tools used by them like filezilla, but i am doing sFTP thru mainframes using ssh script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution..Instead of copying file(PS file) from mainframes to USS in mainframes using JCL step like below

```
//ST020    EXEC PGM=IKJEFT01,COND=(0,NE)                        
//SYSTSPRT DD SYSOUT=*                                          
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                          
//SYSPUNCH DD SYSOUT=*                                          
//ICTRL1   DD DSN=PP00.PA0000.CNTL(H123YC1),DISP=SHR        
//OCTRL1   DD PATH='/u/SPP00/ryc',                              
//            PATHDISP=(KEEP,DELETE),                           
//            PATHOPTS=(OWRONLY,OCREAT,OTRUNC),PATHMODE=SIRWXU  
//SYSTSIN  DD DSN=PP00.PA0000.CNTL(H125CLF),DISP=SHR
```

and

then transfer it using

`ascii
lcd /u/myid
put File1.txt FileNew1.txt
chmod 775 FileNew1.txt`

I have transferred the file dirctly from mainframes to client system(windows), I have used below script for that..

```
lcd /u/SPP00/                                       
!cp -F crnl "//'p125.P123.DEMUT.CSV'" AANBCD   
put AANBCD   Test_AVBCLKS_20160218_085518.csv
!rm AANBCD   
quit
```

This has worked like charmm!!!

Comment: Good work. Saves resource-use as well, which costs on the Mainframe.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the sftp implementation by Dovetailed Technologies https://dovetail.com/products/sftp.html. It supports native MVS data sets including GDGs and PDS(E)s and supports the same set of line feed conversions as cp and then some. It also has a very nice batch launcher and an SFTP server and all the mainframe requirements like SAF security, logging and SMF recording. It's free to use but for production use Dovetailed offer paid support.